# Unable to get image from url

Tags: java, android

I need to get images from url and set it in a listview

Here is my main xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollFeed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:background="#d2d2d2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="^\nRefresh" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15000sp" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nextPosts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40sp"
                android:background="#d2d2d2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="next >>"
                android:layout_weight="50" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/previousPosts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40sp"
                android:background="#d2d2d2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text=" previous" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#abc0e3"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#b1b1b1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

The error appears at `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cover)` as `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION`

Here's the code:

```
if (c.has("picture") == true) {
    try {
        Log.d("IT HAS PICTURE! TADA!!", "Image Found");
        imgUrl = c.getString("picture");
//      Thread thread = new Thread(){
//      public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread Running");
        NewsFeed.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
            //Your code to run in GUI thread here 
            URL newUrl = null;
            try {
                newUrl = new URL(imgUrl);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myBitmap = getBitmapFromUrl(newUrl);
            image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        });
//    }
//  };
    thread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("ERROR LOADING IMAGE","Why you do this, InputStream? Why?");
    }
}else{
    NewsFeed.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        //Your code to run in GUI thread here 
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);
    }
    });
    }
```

Comment: 1. You're not showing where the "image" element is getting initialized or declared.

2. There's no "image" in your xml files either.

Comment: its in the onCreate method as **ImageView image; image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);**, I also tried it initializing it in doInBackground() method but the result was same

Comment: What is error? Also check whether you have initialized the image view in the adapter or not

Comment: there is an ImageView in list_item.xml

Comment: @Fahim - I am not sure how to initialize ImageView in adapter. My adapter is like this : **ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(NewsFeed.this, contactList,
     R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_MESSAGE,
       TAG_CREATETIME }, new int[] { R.id.message,
       R.id.time });
   setListAdapter(adapter);**

Comment: @Fahim It is a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION at **image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve it with a default adapter. You need to create a custom adapter for listview.

In getView method of adapter you need to inflate the list item layout and then have to bind the image to image view.

You can refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) for example